# PHP array_count_values sorted multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
Array
(
    [LEVEL1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [1] => 12
            [2] => 16
            [3] => 12
            [4] => 12
        )

    [LEVEL2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [1] => 18
            [2] => 19
            [3] => 19
            [4] => 16
        )

)
```

I would like to get subtotals sorted by key.

```
Array
(
    [LEVEL1] => Array
        (
            [12] => 3
            [16] => 1
            [18] => 1
        )

    [LEVEL2] => Array
        (
            [19] => 2
            [16] => 2 (rectification on the sorting)
            [18] => 1
        )

)
```

I tried many functions I found in php.net, but didn't even manage to sort it.

I can't get passed the first level.

Thanks
Sebastian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_map()` & `array_count_values()`. Example:

```
$your_arr = Array(
    'LEVEL1' => Array(18,12,16,12,12),
    'LEVEL2' => Array(16,18,19,19,16,)
);

$keys = array_keys($your_arr);
$result = array_combine($keys, array_map(function($v, $k){
    $values = array_count_values($v);
    ($k == 'LEVEL1') ?  ksort($values) : krsort($values);
    return $values;
}, $your_arr, $keys));

print '<pre>';
print_r($result);
print '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [LEVEL1] => Array
        (
            [12] => 3
            [16] => 1
            [18] => 1
        )

    [LEVEL2] => Array
        (
            [19] => 2
            [18] => 1
            [16] => 2
        )
)
```

Comment: I always think, that `array_map` loss array keys... Thanks :)

Comment: Your array isn't sorted like OP wanted. So sort it and your answer is fine!

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my example. it had to be sorted by DESC based on Counts. I rectified it. So I changed the second krsort for arsort, and that works perfectly. Thanks to both.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $array = array (
            "LEVEL1" => array (18, 12, 16, 12, 12),
            "LEVEL2" => array (16, 18, 19, 19, 16)
        );

    $newarray = array();

    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $newarray[$k] = array_count_values($array[$k]);
        if($k == "LEVEL1")
            ksort($newarray[$k]);
        elseif($k == "LEVEL2")
            krsort($newarray[$k]);
    }

    print_r($newarray);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [LEVEL1] => Array
        (
            [12] => 3
            [16] => 1
            [18] => 1
        )

    [LEVEL2] => Array
        (
            [19] => 2
            [18] => 1
            [16] => 2
        )

)
```